# assign shortcut to run current file in debug mode in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

#### Summary

I am looking for an easy way on how to configure `PyCharm` to always target current file for `debug`/`run` commands. Preferably by assigning shortcut to run current file in debug mode in `PyCharm`

#### To elaborate

I have found key bindings for a generic `run`/`debug` commands, but they are only applicable to currently selected `run configuration`:

[image]

What I want to re-map are these commands from the menu:

[image]

As you see there is a default shortcut assigned to `Run` command... which I also want to reconfigure.. But what bugs me the most is that there is no shortcut for `Debug` command. Nor I found the keymap setting for any of those two.

Is this possible to achieve this in current latest `PyCharm` version on Windows? **Maybe by editing some config file directly?**
There was a topic created back in 2017 but no official solution given: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000475424-Remap-the-shortcut-to-run-the-current-file

#### Solution tried

As a workaround solution - I have tried creating following run configuration:

[image]

which results in following error on start:

[image]

Given the output, I am afraid that variable substitution does not work in any other place than `parameter` field..

#### The problem to solve

There is a ton of different `.py` files that I create for testing purposes. It's a nightmare to create a separate build configuration for each of them...

[image]

The problem I am trying to solve - is to be able to start `debugging` for files from the list above without explicitly creating build configurations for each.. None of the files are the entry point of 1 big program. They are independent scripts.

Comment: In the Keymap settings, it's called `Run context configuration` and `Debug context configuration`. The former has a shortcut `Ctrl-Shift-F10` by default, the latter doesn't have a shortcut by default.

Comment: Also, both commands are available in the context menu (on right-click in the editor window) with the green arrow and bug icons.

Comment: @mportes this works!! I must be blind.. missed this hotkey.. If you create a proper answer I will mark it as accepted answer since this is exactly what I have been looking for..

Comment: @mportes I have added my own hacky solution to the problem. It's not to replace your answer, but to add more solutions to the common problem. I think it might be useful for someone so I am not planning to remove the question.. if you agree?

Comment: @Alex I joined my two comments into an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @bad_coder it's not clear what author intended to achieve in that question other than passing argument to the file, which I already knew was possible at the time of writing my own question. My question expands on the actual use-case of what I want to achieve. Using a startup file is just a hack around having an actual key binding for starting the debug of active file. So no, questions are not related. Not directly at least. Regardless we already have 2 solutions to my problem so I am not looking for more options, but you can provide alternative answers in the section down below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Keymap settings, it's called `Run context configuration` and `Debug context configuration`. The former has a shortcut `Ctrl-Shift-F10` by default, the latter doesn't have a shortcut by default.

Also, both commands are available in the context menu (on right-click in the editor window) with the green arrow and bug icons.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question has been provided by @mported.

While waiting for response I was able to create another solution that also "works".

Create a file called `main.py` the root directory of the project. Create a new run configuration, where script accepts 2 parameters: `$FileDir$` and `$FileNameWithoutAllExtensions$`. Select main file as a startup module. It should look like this:

[image]

What the main module does - is it uses the second parameter to include the target script as a module. First parameters is used to include the module location.

`main.py`

```py
import sys
import os
import importlib

# Count the arguments
arguments = sys.argv
argumentsLength = len(arguments) - 1
print ("The script is called with %i arguments" % (argumentsLength))

if argumentsLength != 2:
    raise Exception('Invalid argument count')

fileDir = sys.argv[1]
print (f"filePath={fileDir}")

fileNameWithoutExtension = arguments[2]
print (f"fileNameWithoutExtension={fileNameWithoutExtension}")

# By default, you can't. When importing a file, Python only searches the directory that the entry-point script
# is running from and sys.path which includes locations such as the package installation directory
sys.path.insert(1, fileDir)

print (f"Executing module")
print (f"================================================")
importlib.import_module(fileNameWithoutExtension)
```

This approach might be useful to someone. It allows you step into/debug the code as you normally would.

However, given the initial request details - **@mported**'s answer is more correct and therefore is an accepted answer.